# Looking for a Mac Calendar application that provides alarms and only shows up in the menu bar (i.e. not in the dock or app switcher)

Tags: macos, mac, calendar, calendar.app

Most of the features of iCal are fine for me, except I don't want my calendar application to appear on the dock or--especially--in the Cmd+Tab app switcher. I'm looking for a calendar application that meets the following requirements:

1. Syncs with Google Calendar
2. Has alarms
3. Doesn't appear on the dock or in the app switcher. Instead, it should only be accessible via the menu bar (like next to the wi-fi control).

Comment: `I'm looking for a calendar application that meets the following requirements:` - Was a search engine of no use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that [Fantastical by Flexibits](http://flexibits.com/fantastical) is an app that will meet your needs.

It is accessed from your menu bar and also syncs with Google Calendar, as well as other calendar programs for the Mac.